# Override properties of a predefined listing style

Tags: listings, languages, html, keywords

I use the `listings` package and I want to override an attribute of the HTML style.

Unfortunately my code overrides the whole HTML style and not just a single property:

```
\lstloadlanguages{HTML}
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML}{ndkeywords={charset, window, document}}
```

Does anyone know how I can only override `ndkeywords`?

Comment: how about (for example) `\lstset{emph={charset,window,document},emphstyle={\color{green!50!black}}}` (for reference see page 17 of the documentation)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Package `listings` allows the definition of styles, there you can put the options to format the special HTML code listings. Also the keywords, which should be displayed differently, needs to be removed from the default class first. Then the example adds these keywords to class 2 and avoids the use of `ndkeywords`, because this is marked *deprecated* in the documentation of `listings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}
\lstdefinestyle{myHTML}{
  language=HTML,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  deletekeywords={charset, document, window},
  morekeywords={[2]{charset, document, window}},
  keywordstyle={[2]{\color{red}}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myHTML]
<HTML>
  <HEAD></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <A href="http://tex.stackexchange.com"
       charset="US-ASCII">TeX.SE</A>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]